# AWS Spinnaker (Invalid IamInstanceProfile ) issue while deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

Spinnaker ,
provider AWS.

Exception ( Monitor Deploy )
Invalid IamInstanceProfile: BaseIAMRole (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: phannib74ffa48-xxxxxxxxx-53268f3)
[image]

Comment: added All roles permssions like autoscalling ,ec2full,poweruser,admin permssions...

Comment: please post your `hal config` output. It is using the BaseIAMRole as the default user. What is the AWS user or role that was configured???

Answer (score 0):

1. Review you have correctly added the AWS EC2 and ECS (if needed) providers to spinnaker
2. Follow instructrions to set your deployment from either Role or [user](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/add-aws-account/).
3. Double check the [steps](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ec2/) for AWS EC2 provider. Specially the AWS IAM policies and trust relationship between roles and users.
4. Even upgrading spinnaker after reviewing the items before can help.